# Can Pod/Service still work if kube-master or etcd service down?

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

If kube-master or etcd service down in my kubernetes cluster, can my Pod/Service still work? Also, if the network is still work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The containers in a pod continue to run, yes. If the master components are not available this means no new pods/services can be launched, but existing ones continue to operate. Note that this behaviour is also one of the good practices and lessons learned from [Borg](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub43438.html).

Comment: What for the network thing? For example, one Pod want to communicate with other Service via service virtual IP? I know the communication is through kube-proxy on each minion, but have question on whether kube-proxy still work without etcd or master?

Comment: Depends on the service discovery mechanism but in general: as long as the Endpoint is up, it should work, see also http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/services.html

Comment: All components should "coast" with their last known state as long as the master is down.